# Add user account with live-build

Tags: debian, customization, debian-stretch

I'm building a custom live distribution using the live-build tool. In particular, I'm modifying a Debian stretch distribution (amd64 arch, MATE desktop environment). I'm trying to add more user account, in order to choose between them when the live starts. I tried adding a chroot hook with the adduser command but when I boot the system I always have only one user account. Is there a way to do such thing? Thank you. If you need more details on the system I'm customizing please ask.

Comment: I'm trying to do this today, but with a Kali live-build image (so I have more than just a root user) so equally interested in an answer!